# What is this Excel formula doing?

Tags: excel, formula

Can someone please explain in English wtf this formula is doing? I'm looking at someone else's work and have no idea.

```
=SUM(OFFSET(INDIRECT((ADDRESS(ROW(),21)),0,0,1)CurrentActualPeriod))
```

Comment: Are you sure the parentheses are correct as pasted above?  Does the formula evaluate to an error?

Comment: Are you missing a comma right before `CurrentActualPeriod`?

Answer (score 3):

Agreeing with jeffreymb, you can also use the Evaluate Formula function in Excel to step through the nested functions one at a time (if you have Excel 2007).  Here is documentation and a screenshot on how that works:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-HP010066254.aspx

Comment: if you can't do this, then put each level of nesting into it's own cell, and refer back as you build up your nests...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, without data I'm no better off than you are. I would suggest breaking each of the functions out into their own cell so that you can see what they are returning. This will allow you to make yourself some kind of call stack so you can see what is happening.

Just by looking at this I'm pretty sure it could be simplified substantially. In my years of Excel development, I don't recall ever having to resort to the Address function. Offset is pretty powerful and confusing when used correctly. :-)

Comment: I just read the `OFFSET` help file. It does seem to be quite confusing! and I can see the power in it...

Answer (score 0):

I use the `ADDRESS` and `INDIRECT` functions quite often.

Does the formula actually work? If it does, which version of Excel are you using? I can't get it to work in Excel 2003.

For me, the `ADDRESS` function has too few argument, and the ones there are wrong...; it should be (something like) `ADDRESS(ROW(),21,1,1,1)`

The `CurrentActualPeriod` probably refers to a named range, and should probably have a comma before it.

I can't do much more than that atm..

Comment: Seconded, I am here with excel 2007 and can't get it to work either.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this formula appears in D4, then:

```
= SUM(
      OFFSET(
             INDIRECT(
                 (
                   ADDRESS(
                      ROW(),21
                   )
                 ),0,0,1
             )
             CurrentActualPeriod
      )
  )

ROW() = 4

ADDRESS(4,21) = $U$4

INDIRECT($U$4) = take contents of $U$4, use as address, and get that cell's value

OFFSET(..., 0, 0, 1) = ?
```

The rest appears to be a syntax error, unless there's a missing comma before `CurrentActualPeriod`.

The double indirection sure is confusing. Build an address, get a cell address from there, use it for ANOTHER level of indirection... Ouch

Comment: I have done worse things when I need an extremely dynamic named range. I would move horizontally, vertically and change it's height!